# Can't login to CentOs graphic interface

Tags: linux, centos, login

My problem occur when I try to login on my CentOs 6.7 virtual machine in the GUI, the login interface is just reloaded on valid password. In the text interface, I can login with no issue. I've try login in as root in the GUI, it worked.

I've tried creating a new user, I can login with this new account.

My guess would be a sort of lock.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question, It was nothing about a lock and was quite simple. The issue came from bash.

I've been testing some zsh scripting lately. I some how erased my .bashrc (really bad idea) and created a blank one. This never affected me, because I had zsh as default shell. But yesterday, when trying to start bash, I've set bash as default shell.

I just copied the .bashrc from the new user to my session, now everything works.